# Standard notation/operator to "stacking" block matrices?

Tags: matrices, block-matrices

I looking for some operator or compact notation to stacking vertically and horizontally several matrices (indexed and not indexed). More specifically, i want to represent in a compact way (ie, as an "inline" equation) the following block matrix:

1. $ \begin{bmatrix}A_1 & A_2 &  \cdots & A_C\end{bmatrix}$, where $A_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, C$, are matrices with the same number of rows.
2. $ \begin{bmatrix}B_1 \\ B_2 \\  \vdots \\ B_C\end{bmatrix}$, where $B_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, C$, are matrices with the same number of columns.
3. $ \overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}I &  \cdots & I\end{bmatrix}}^{\text{C times}}$  and
   $ \left.\begin{bmatrix}I  \\  \vdots \\ I\end{bmatrix}\right\}{\text{C times}}$

where $I$ is an identity matrix.

Is there a standard notation/operator to denote those block matrices?

PS.: I have found the question [Notation for juxtaposition operation on matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194893/notation-for-juxtaposition-operation-on-matrices), but the answer to that question is not what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kronecker products and standard
basis vectors $\{e_k\}$ the first two cases are summations
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{k=1}^C\,e_k^T\otimes A_k \qquad\qquad
B &= \sum_{k=1}^C\,e_k\otimes B_k \\
}$$
By invoking the Einstein summation convention,
one could even omit the sigmas.

The third is a special case of these with $\:A_k=I\;\:{\rm or}\;\:B_k=I$

Comment: Thanks for the reply @greg, but I was looking for a more straightforward notation. Maybe it will be more convenient for me to introduce a new specific notation for those matrices in my paper.